# PHP - Can not access the checkbox value that has been checked

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, checkbox

For my databases project I am doing this form where a user can select the information he wants and it will be displayed on a html page. For the time being I am implementing only the checkboxes where I am encountering a problem.

The problem is that when I check the checkboxes (for my current implementation I am only interested in the case where the user checks "Location"+ "Pipe-Type" + "Amount") in my action page "fe_page2.php", the if condition that checks to see if the checkboxes are checked is never being reached instead it always goes to the else condition. The code is provided below.

This is my basic html page:

```
    <html>  
<head>
    <title>Flow Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="margin-left: 450px">Retrieve Flow Element Information</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="fe_page2.php" method="post">
    All Times:
    <input type="checkbox" name="alltimes" onchange="changeFields()"><br><br>
    Start Date:
    <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate">
    Start Time:
    <input type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime"><br><br>
    Same Time:
    <input type="checkbox" name="sametime" id = "sametime" onchange="sameFields()"><br><br> 
    End Date:
    <input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate">
    End Time:
    <input type="time" name="endtime" id="endtime"><br><br>

    <h3> Select fields of output</h3>
    <hr>

    Pipe Key: <input type="text" name="pipepirmary" id="pipekey"><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="pipelocation" id="pipeLocation" value="value1" >
    Location<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Pipe-Type" id="pipetype" value="value2">
    Pipe-Type<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" id="amount" value="value3">
    Amount<br><br>

    Flow Element:<input type="text" name="fepirmarykey" id="fekey"/><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="flow" id="flo">
    Flow<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="temperature" id="temp">
    Temperature<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="pressure" id="pres">
    Pressure<br><br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
    <script>
        function changeFields() {

            if(document.getElementById("startdate").disabled == false){
                document.getElementById("startdate").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("starttime").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("enddate").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("sametime").disabled = true;
                if(document.getElementById("sametime").checked = true){
                    document.getElementById("sametime").checked = false;
                    }
                document.getElementById("startdate").value = null;
                document.getElementById("starttime").value = null;
                document.getElementById("enddate").value = null;
                document.getElementById("endtime").value = null;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("startdate").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("starttime").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("enddate").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("sametime").disabled = false;
            }

        }
        function sameFields() {
            if(document.getElementById("enddate").disabled == false){
                document.getElementById("enddate").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("enddate").value = null;
                document.getElementById("endtime").value = null;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("enddate").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("endtime").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the php page fe_page2.php

```
<?php

 require('dbconf.inc');

 db_connect();

 print"<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
 print"</pre>";

 $pipelocation = $_POST[pipelocation];
 $pipetype = $_POST[Pipe-Type];
 $pipeamount = $_POST[amount];

 if($pipelocation=='value1' && $pipetype == 'value2' && $pipeamount == 'value3'){

    $qrySel="SELECT `Pipe_ID`, `Location`, `Amount`, `PipeType` FROM pipe order by Pipe_ID desc";
    $resSel = mysql_query($qrySel);

    if($resSel){

        while($rowpipe = mysql_fetch_array($resSel, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo "Pipe ID:{$rowpipe['Pipe_ID']} <br> ".
            "Location: {$rowpipe['Location']} <br> ".
            "Amount: {$rowpipe['Amount']} <br>".
            "PipeType: {$rowpipe['PipeType']} <br>".
            "--------------------------------<br>";
        }

        echo "Fetched Data Successfully!\n";    

    }
 }
 else{
    echo"never went in!";
 }

 db_close();



?>
```

I have tried different things such as

```
if(isset($pipelocation) && isset($pipetype) && isset($pipeamount)){
     .....
}
```

and removing the value from html page and using the following piece of code:

```
 if($pipelocation == 'on' && $pipetype == 'on' && $pipeamount == 'on'){
               ...
    }
```

But still no luck...
Any help would be appreciated.

The code that is presented is purely my work but does include pieces of code that comes from the provided reference below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZtXYa9eGGw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotations here:

```
$pipelocation = $_POST['pipelocation'];
$pipetype = $_POST['Pipe-Type'];
$pipeamount = $_POST['amount'];
```

Comment: Oh god, Thank you. I feel so dumb right now. Thanks once again!

Comment: Sometime it happens. Nothing to worry.